# How can I create runtime object of my Polygon? What does the value of RenderTransform refer to?

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, rendertransform

I am going to create a hexagon shape in WPF and found this XAML code:

```
 <Polygon Points="14,0 7,12.1243556529821 -7,12.1243556529821 -14,1.71444889535133E-15 -7.00000000000001,-12.1243556529821 7,-12.1243556529821"
Fill="Black" Stroke="#FF000000" StrokeThickness="1" 
RenderTransform="0.866025403784439,0.5,-0.5,0.866025403784439,31,19.2487113059643" />
```

But I have two questions:

**First:**
For what refer these values (0.866025403784439,0.5,-0.5,0.866025403784439,31,19.2487113059643) of RenderTransform property?

**Second:**
How can I create a runtime object from this Polygon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: It's the six values M11, M12, M21, M22, OffsetX and OffsetY that define the [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635216.aspx) of a [MatrixTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635220.aspx).

Second: [Polygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615638.aspx) is already a "runtime object". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer (by checking the accept tick) to mark the question as answered.